# Compute for the summation of X^2

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application

Given x = 3;

I need to compute for the summation of the value of `x = 3 + 2 + 1`

`x = 6;`

```
int input = 3;
int retVal = 0;

for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++)
{
    retVal += i;            
}
Console.WriteLine(retVal);
```

I was able to compute for the summation of x.

How can i compute for the value of summation of x^2

for example

```
x         x^2

1         1 
2         4
3         9

summation of x = 6
summation of x^2 = 14
```

I have tried the following code

```
int input = 3;
int retVal = 0;
int summation = input * input;
for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++)
{
    retVal += i;
    summation +=  i;
}
Console.WriteLine(retVal);
Console.WriteLine(summation);
```

Comment: Variable names like `retVal` and shifting from `x` in the description to `i` in the code are perhaps blocking your thinking and writing. Try `sumOfX` and `sumOfXSquared`. Programming is storytelling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compute for the summation of X\*Y and Summation of X^2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32501838/compute-for-the-summation-of-xy-and-summation-of-x2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int input = 3;
int retVal = 0;
int summation = 0;  //<=Chnaged from input * input
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)  //<=Changed from 0 to 1
{
    retVal += i;
    summation +=  i * i;  //<= changed from i
}
Console.WriteLine(retVal);
Console.WriteLine(summation);
```

Comment: instead of using summation +=  i * i; you can use summation +=Math.Pow(i, 2), but it is the same

Comment: @Jamaxack Thank you for your comment, Good point, I didn't use Math.Pow() because it works with double and needs type casting and the answer needs more changes, that I preferred avoid that for this user:)

Answer (score 4):

Let me explain you your code:

```
      int input = 3;
        int retVal = 0;
        int summation = input * input; //summation is equal to 9
        for (int i = 0; i <= input; i++)
        {
            retVal += i; 
            summation +=  i; /*this is basically saying add summation plus i 
                               tosummation (9 is assigned 9 + 0 so summation is still 9). Then, when i is 1, 
                               summation changes to 10. When i is 2, summation changes to 12, and when i is 3,
                               summation is 15. What you should be doing is initialize summation to 0 and in 
                               the for loop, do this: summation +=  i * i (summation is assigned summation + (i * i)) Also, no need to start i from 0 (it is doing one extra loop for nothing). You should start i from 1. */
        }
        Console.WriteLine(retVal);
        Console.WriteLine(summation); //Another user already provided the solution. I just wanted to explain you your code.
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to stackoverflow. I don't know how to break line.

Comment: @Jamaxack You are right the summation is 15 here. I didn't write the solution. I just copied the questioner's code and added comments explaining why her code was wrong. The solution is already provided by other users

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.Range()` to achieve this.

```
public static int Summation(int count, Func<int, int> series)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, count).Select(series).Sum();
}
```

Example of use - `Summation(3, x => x * x)` would return `14`.

Comment: Good solution can you please explain this more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You need to take power of value before adding by using [Math.Pow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var input = 3;
var summation = 0;
var power = 2;
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++) //initialize i = 1 because first entry is 1 don't start it from 0
{
    summation += (int)Math.Pow(i, power);
}
Console.WriteLine(summation);
```